# check/parse email account for new messages using C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, parsing, email

I have a windows machine that i want to write a C# or VB.net program to check an email account i own. This email account is a webmail (fatcow). I can also forward it to my gmail. What libraries are available that allow me to periodically check it (every 1 minute?) and parse the data in the body/subject and then send a response email.

Ideally, this program can queue up emails that are new and check up the quue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the Gmail API's for hooking up to a gmail account and doing various things.

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/

Also you can take a look at some of the various open source email clients.

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/download-email-client-for-linux-mac-osx-windows.html

Those should give you a fairly good place to start. Also I believe I have seen simplistic email client tutorials around on the internet such as:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34495/Building-your-own-Mail-Client-using-C